# android - saving a picture from user's gallery

Tags: android

Here is my code. I'm having problems with showing and saving the pic picked from the user's gallery, whilst when I do it from the camera it works just fine for me.
here is how the user is reffered to his gallery-

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAddDucuments) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setMessage("to add documents");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("from camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // user choose to take a picture

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("from gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // user choose to pick a photo from gallery

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);                }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
```

and here is how the picture is supposed to be saved. I need it both as a String (so I can use it further on) and in the ImageView that is in this avtivity (named imgTheDocument).

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

            StringImgDocument = BitMapToString(bitmap);

            imgTheDocument.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I run this code the activity stops after pressing on the wanted picture. I can't understand where is the problem. I have used this code before and it worked just fine.

I'll appriciate any help!! Thanks:)

my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Why would you save a picture you selected from the'gallery'? That picture is already on your device then.

Comment: ???? You are not saving a picture you picked from the gallery. Which code would do that?

Comment: `StringImgDocument = BitMapToString(bitmap);` What is happening with that code?

Answer (score 0):

the intent to pick image(This is Error free and works on all android versions!)

```
Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_FROM_GALLERY);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
```

This is for onActivityResult

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                //you can both use the selectedImageUri or yourSelectedImagePath for working the Image you picked,send it somewhere or store it in database or etc..
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String yourSelectedImagePath = selectedImage.tostring;
                //I just use the Uri to display the selected image in an imageview
                yourImageView.setImageUri(selectedImage);

        }
```